# What is `gpytorch.settings.max_preconditioner_size`? And `gpytorch.beta_features.checkpoint_kernel(checkpoint_size)`?

Tags: python, pytorch, gpytorch

I am following the tutorial [Simple_MultiGPU_GP_Regression](https://gpytorch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/01_Simple_GP_Regression/Simple_MultiGPU_GP_Regression.html) and I noticed that during the training two options were established:

```
    with gpytorch.beta_features.checkpoint_kernel(checkpoint_size), \
         gpytorch.settings.max_preconditioner_size(preconditioner_size):
```

What are or refer to the variables `checkpoint_kernel` and `preconditioner_size`?

I have check the documentation [preconditioner_size](https://gpytorch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#gpytorch.settings.max_preconditioner_size) but it is not quite clear to me what it refers to.

I intuit that `checkpoint_size` refers to something related to the number of training points associated with each GPU. But it is just an intuition.

Help is appreciated.

Thanks